# Isometries (reflection matrix) and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection

Suppose I have a matrix
$$F=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.6&0.8\\
0.8&-0.6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is clearly a reflection matrix.

Furthermore, I have found $\lambda_1 = 1,\vec{v}_1=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$
and 
$\lambda_2=-1, \vec{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix}$, how do I exploit the fact that the eigenvectors associate with these two eigenvalues form a basis to determine the effect of $F$ on a vector
 $\vec{w}=
\begin{pmatrix}3\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$
which will give $F\vec{w}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
3
\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w = v_1 + v_2$

$Fw = Fv_1 + Fv_2 = \lambda_1v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 = v_1 - v_2$

Answer (score 1):

Your eigenvalues indicate that one eigenvector is preserved by $F$, and the other is reversed in direction.  The one preserved lies on the axis of symmetry through which $F$ reflects.

Thus, you want to write your $\vec{w}$ as a linear combination of these two eigenvectors.  And then apply $F$.

Comment: Hi, I have added eigenvectors. Can you show me the algebra?

Comment: @chuck, Doug M did the algebra in the other answer.  And, yes, he did what I meant.